# Does google app engine mapreduce pipeline library not use webapp2?

Tags: google-app-engine

The mapreduce pipeline code doesn't seem to be using webapp2 and ndb, and requires threadsafe to be off.  Does that mean I have to update the code to use webapp2 and threadsafe?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the [latest MapReduce framework](http://appengine-mapreduce.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/src/mapreduce):

1. MapReduce supports both db and ndb.
2. MapReduce uses webapp but you do not need to upgrade to webapp2. They both use the WSGI standard and run just fine side by side.
3. MapReduce works fine with `threadsafe: true` with small changes.

   #### mapreduce/main.py:

   ```
   def create_application():
       return webapp.WSGIApplication(create_handlers_map(),
                                     debug=True)

   mapreduce_app = create_application()
   ```

   #### app.yaml:

   ```
   - url: /mapreduce/pipeline/images
     static_dir: mapreduce/lib/pipeline/ui/images
   - url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
     script: mapreduce.main.mapreduce_app
     login: admin
   ```